# Destroy Session but keep flashdata

Tags: php, session, codeigniter, tankauth

I am using [Tank Auth](http://www.konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/) for user management in my CI 1.7.3 App. Everything is working fine but I'm trying to set a `flash_message` to be displayed when the user logs out. The problem is the `$this->tank_auth->logout();` function destroys the session. I have modified the logout function in the Tank Auth library to look like:

```
    function logout()   {
        $this->delete_autologin();

        // See http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewreply/662369/ as the reason for the next line
        $user_session_data = array('user_id' => '', 'username' => '', 'status' => '');
        $this->ci->session->set_userdata($user_session_data);
        $this->ci->session->unset_userdata($user_session_data);
    }
```

It was previously

```
function logout()
        {
            $this->delete_autologin();

            // See http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewreply/662369/ as the reason for the next line
            $this->ci->session->set_userdata(array('user_id' => '', 'username' => '', 'status' => ''));

            $this->ci->session->sess_destroy();
        }
```

In My controller I have

```
function logout(){
    if ($this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) { // logged in
        $this->session->set_flashdata('status_message', $this->lang->line('auth_message_logged_out'));
        $this->tank_auth->logout();

        redirect('');           

    }
```

}

If I remove the `$this->tank_auth->logout();` function the message shows fine. I'm sure it's a simple session problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you try to set flashdata while using a database in the same request after you call `sess_destroy()`, it won't work (because there is no session to append the flashdata to).

To fix this problem, add `$this->ci->session->sess_create();` after the call to `sess_destroy()`. This works because you're re-creating the session before trying to append data to it. This is the only way to use flashdata after a `sess_destroy()` if you're using sessions in a database.

Answer (score 2):

The `sess_destroy()` function destroys also the session flash variables used to pass the message.

U already answered your question, in the library `logout()` function, you need to replace

```
$this->ci->session->sess_destroy();
```

with

```
$this->ci->session->unset_userdata(array('user_id' => '', 'username' => '', 'status' => ''));
```

This will not completely destroy the session, only the user data used for login, so I recommend instead, to modify the `logout()` function in the controller and show the message manually, by passing it to a view.

Answer (score 1):

While this is a workaround, it might do the trick for you...

wherever you're displaying these, I'll be assuming you're checking in the view so...

```
<? if ($this->session->flashdata('status_messege'): ?>

    <p><?= $this->session->flashdata('status_message') ?></p>

<? endif; ?>
```

you **COULD** add an elseif to that and check for the referrer being your logout function...

```
<? if ($this->session->flashdata('status_messege'): ?>

    <p><?= $this->session->flashdata('status_message') ?></p>

<? else if ($this->agent->referrer() == site_url('path/to/logout'): ?>

    <p><?= $this->lang->line('auth_message_logged_out') ?></p>

<? endif; ?>
```

A bit of a hackish way to overcome this issue, but probably a way nonetheless.