# CI Session Not Wokoring After Change Email Codeigniter/Tank Auth

Tags: codeigniter, session, tankauth

Hi I have my session set to true in codeigniter I use tank auth but when I go use my change email form. after re activating new email got to success page but loads up errors  but when I view my database users table email has changed.

The errors that I am showing are.

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: session_id
Filename: libraries/Session.php
Line Number: 272

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: ip_address
Filename: libraries/Session.php
Line Number: 272

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: user_agent
Filename: libraries/Session.php
Line Number: 272

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: last_activity
Filename: libraries/Session.php
Line Number: 272

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: session_id
Filename: libraries/Session.php
Line Number: 288

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: last_activity
Filename: libraries/Session.php
Line Number: 289

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/cws01/public_html/tank/system/core/Exceptions.php:185)
Filename: libraries/Session.php
Line Number: 675

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/cws01/public_html/tank/system/core/Exceptions.php:185)
Filename: helpers/url_helper.php
Line Number: 542

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is due to the sess_destroy() initiated by a logout in Tank_auth
Following code in logout function within the Tank_auth library worked for me.

```
function logout()
{
  $this->tank_auth->logout(); // Destroys session
  $this->ci->session->sess_create();
  redirect('/auth/login');
}
```

See: [Post on ellislab-forum](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/230846/#1062498); and [this forum..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332714/destroy-session-but-keep-flashdata)